# Create a random decimal number in bash

Tags: bash

I am programming in bash. I return a function f, lets say f=logn. I now want to add an error up to 5 percent to that function.

Therefore now I use :

```
my_log=$(echo "l($i)" | bc -l)
echo $my_log |bc
```

However I want to return

```
my_log=$(echo "l($i)" | bc -l)
error = (a RANDOM NUMBER from 0 to 0.05)*$my_log
echo $my_log+$error |bc
```

How do I calculate that `RANDOM NUMBER from 0 to 0.05`?

Answer (score 3):

A random number from 0 to 0.05:

```
rand=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $(printf '0.%02d' $(( $RANDOM % 100))) / 2")
```

Answer (score 2):

Working with the `$RANDOM` directly in Bash is probably possible but I'd just farm it out to another language just because it's easier to predict. Perl seems to be the simplest to rand and format.

```
error=$(perl -e 'printf("%.2f\n", rand()/2)')
```

Instead of working out your log then working out an error multiplied by that and adding it on, you could just add `1` to the error and multiply the first result in one step:

```
error=$(perl -e 'printf("%.2f\n", rand()/2 + 1)')
echo "l($i) * $error" | bc -l
```

I guess there's also an argument for staying in one language (rather than punting a number between things as a string). We still have to pass `$i` in but we can handle the rest in Perl:

```
export i=2
perl -e 'print log($ENV{i})*(rand()/2+1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash `$RANDOM` generates integers only, you could use `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random`.

Here is a Python one liner embed inside a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# get a decimal random from the range of 0.0 up to 0.05
result=$(python -c "import random;print(random.uniform(0.0, 0.05))")
# do something with the generated random
echo $result
```